# method for creating a unique validation key/number

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm using django for a web-magazine with subscriber-content.  when a user purchases a subscription, the site will create a validation key, and send it to the user email address.
The validation key would be added to a list of "valid keys" until it is used.

What is the best method for creating a simple yet unique key?  Can someone suggest a standard python library for key-creation/validation/ect?

This might be a very simple question, but I'm very new. ;)

Comment: Amazing - Thanks guys.  I accepted Gardner, since he also included the tip on django extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other posters mentioned, you are looking for a GUID, of which the most popular implemntation UUID (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier)) . Django extensions (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/)) offer a UUID field just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a GUID. They are quickly becoming industry standard for this kind of thing.

See how to create them here: [How to create a GUID/UUID in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use a GUID. As you said it would be stored as a valid key.