# python: convert UUID to a string which is a C unsigned char[16] initializer

Tags: python

(in case you're curious about motivation: this will be used in a [scons](http://www.scons.org/) build to generate a C file containing a GUID)

I found the question about [generating a GUID in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python). But I don't really know much about programming python. Could someone help me convert this to a string of the form

```
"{0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**, 0x**}"
```

where the **'s are filled in with the GUID bytes in 2-digit hex form?

```
def getInitializer(someUUID):
    hexByteList = [??? for b in someUUID.bytes]
    return '{'+(', '.join(hexByteList))+'}'
```

I'm not sure what to use for the "???" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hex(ord(b))
```

...

Comment: (what if I wanted to ensure the string had constant length by printing byte values from 0-15 as 0x00, 0x01, etc. instead of 0x0, 0x1, etc.?)

Comment: I think `"%#04x" % ord(b)` will do that.