# python: how to convert a valid uuid from String to UUID?

Tags: python, uuid

I receive the data as

```
   {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "parent": "Uncategorized",
        "uuid": "06335e84-2872-4914-8c5d-3ed07d2a2f16"
    },
```

and I need to convert the `uuid` from `String` to `uuid`

I did not find a way on the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html), or am I missing something basic here?

Comment: You may want to check out [this other question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python?rq=1) and also [the docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html). :)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Just pass it to `uuid.UUID`:

```
import uuid

o = {
    "name": "Unknown",
    "parent": "Uncategorized",
    "uuid": "06335e84-2872-4914-8c5d-3ed07d2a2f16"
}

print uuid.UUID(o['uuid']).hex
```

Answer (score 38):

Don't call `.hex` on the UUID object unless you need the string representation of that uuid.

```
>>> import uuid
>>> some_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
>>> type(some_uuid)
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
>>> some_uuid_str = some_uuid.hex
>>> some_uuid_str
'5b77bdbade7b4fcb838f8111b68e18ae'
>>> type(some_uuid_str)
<class 'str'>
```

Then as others mentioned above to convert a uuid string back to UUID instance do:

```
>>> uuid.UUID(some_uuid_str)
UUID('5b77bdba-de7b-4fcb-838f-8111b68e18ae')
>>> (some_uuid == uuid.UUID(some_uuid_str))
True
>>> (some_uuid == some_uuid_str)
False
```

You could even set up a small helper utility function to validate the `str` and return the UUID back if you wanted to:

```
def is_valid_uuid(val):
    try:
        return uuid.UUID(str(val))
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Then to use it:

```
>>> some_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
>>> is_valid_uuid(some_uuid)
UUID('aa6635e1-e394-463b-b43d-69eb4c3a8570')
>>> type(is_valid_uuid(some_uuid))
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

Answer (score 11):

If the above answer didn't work for you for converting a valid UUID in string format back to an actual UUID object... using `uuid.UUID(your_uuid_string)` worked for me.

```
In [6]: import uuid
   ...:
   ...: o = {
   ...:     "name": "Unknown",
   ...:     "parent": "Uncategorized",
   ...:     "uuid": "06335e84-2872-4914-8c5d-3ed07d2a2f16"
   ...: }
   ...:
   ...: print uuid.UUID(o['uuid']).hex
   ...: print type(uuid.UUID(o['uuid']).hex)
06335e84287249148c5d3ed07d2a2f16
<type 'str'>

In [7]: your_uuid_string = uuid.UUID(o['uuid']).hex

In [8]: print uuid.UUID(your_uuid_string)
06335e84-2872-4914-8c5d-3ed07d2a2f16

In [9]: print type(uuid.UUID(your_uuid_string))
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@slajma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54829540/2564892) here is a utility function that returns True/False:

```
def is_valid_uuid(val):
try:
    uuid.UUID(str(val))
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```