# Python Error converting value "AddmissionGuid" to System.GUID

Tags: python, json, signalr, uuid, guid

I am receiving data from a request as follows

```
[
  {
    "Info": {
      "SoftwareVersion": "111",
      "IpAddress": "111.111.11",
      "DeviceName": "1111222",
      "Type": "Tablet"
    },
    "DeviceIdentity": "Identity",
    "AdmissionGuid": "db128362-f942-47fb-b18e-c073aa03b95d",
    "UserId": "8c7be5ac-9f2e-42aa-8f17-4e935a85eff3",
    "ConnectionId": "f78f544e-0780-4b07-87ec-d4edbe4cb522",
    "PairingId": null
  }
]
```

Then I am trying to parse it in python everything works i get the value as expected but i get the following error, I have tried to convert it to Object, String, Hex but nothing works

> Error converting value "AdmissionGuid" to System.GUID

Python script

```
from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection
import threading, time, json, logging
import urllib.request
import requests
import uuid


GetPatientID = requests.get('http://example-url.com/api/json')



 data = GetAdmissionID.json()
print (type(data))

AdmissionGuid= uuid.UUID(data[0]["AdmissionGuid"])
print (type(AdmissionGuid))

UserID = "8c7be5ac-9f2e-42aa-8f17-4e935a85eff3"
softwareVersion = "111"
IpAddress = "111.111.11"
machineName = "1111222"
DeviceType = "Tablet"
pairingId = "null"
def __init__(self, cli):
    self.cli = cli
    logging.info("registered the cli (main thread)")




with Session() as session:
    connection = Connection("http://example-url.com/signalr", session)
    print(connection)
    logging.info("got the connection")
    presenceservice = connection.register_hub('ClientRegistration')
    logging.info("got the hub")

    connection.start()
    def get_data(notificaition):
        print("Recived something?: ", notificaition)
    def print_error(error):
        print('error: ', error)
    connection.error += print_error
    presenceservice.server.invoke('IdentifyClient', 'devideIdentity', 'softwareVersion', 'ipAddress',
                                          'machineName', 'deviceType', 'patientAdmissionGuid', 'patientId', 'pairingId')
    key = input("Press E\n")
    if key == 'e':
        connection.wait(1)

        presenceservice.client.on('Notification', get_data)

        print ('Nothing Happned')



    connection.wait(30)
```

And the log

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
Press E
e
error:  Error converting value "AdmissionGuid" to type 'System.Guid'.
```

Note: I am also using Singal R libary to invoke a C# Hub to register a client.

`AdmissionGuid` is Generated in C# using the GUID library,

Is there a way to get in python ?

I have looked at this already [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859156/python-how-to-convert-a-valid-uuid-from-string-to-uuid), But this does not solve my problem

***EDIT***
C# Function i am Calling with singal R

```
IdentifyClient(string devideIdentity, string softwareVersion, string ipAddress, string machineName, string deviceType, Guid AdmissionGuid, Guid UserID, string pairingId)
```

Comment: GUID is Microsoft's implementation of the UUID standard. Why would you need the conversion anyway? is its current value not sufficient as a unique string?

Comment: Have you tried to remove all non alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @EvyatarMeged I tried to use it as a string but I am getting the same error

Comment: @sousatg Yes i did still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue, I was Invoking the `IdentifyClient()` function with String rather than variables it was a simple fix.

Changed this

```
presenceservice.server.invoke('IdentifyClient', 'devideIdentity', 'softwareVersion', 'ipAddress',
                                          'machineName', 'deviceType', 'patientAdmissionGuid', 'patientId', 'pairingId')
```

To this

```
presenceservice.server.invoke('IdentifyClient', devideIdentity, softwareVersion, ipAddress,
                                          machineName, deviceType, patientAdmissionGuid, patientId, pairingId)
```