# Is there any module in Python for generating random strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any module in Python for generating random strings but to be unique ?
I need to generate keys like for example when installing Windows.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous. Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python?

Comment: to generate a random bytestring (not necessarily unique), you could use `os.urandom(size)`. `ssl.RAND_bytes(size)` (Python 3.3) provides cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you haven't specified the format of the string you want to get, I suppose it doesn't matter, so I suggest simply using UUIDs.

```
>>> import uuid
>>> str(uuid.uuid4())
  > '3afc84bb-6d73-4482-806a-6b3a29e43bca'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want only letters, for example, here's code to generate a random string of a random length upto 1000:

```
out = ''
for i in range(random.random()*100):
    out += random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz')
```

You can modify your alphabet of course.