# Is it possible to generate a random and unique 5 digit ID for my sqlite database?

Tags: javascript, python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to generate an ID for each entry in my db table. It would look like this: nov45833.

The first three characters are unique to the name of my table, nov for novel, com for comic, etc. The next 5 digits are a randomly generated number. If I wanted to delete the entry, I would simply call the stored ID for the entry (e.g. .../delete/nov45833) to do so. I would also like the IDs to be unique (so I don't delete the wrong entry).

My original plan was to click a button as I'm filling out my form that will generate a random number and show the value in the specified form field. Then I would complete the form as intended. Here is an example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzEfy)

Would I have to do this on the server-side or with JavaScript? I am working with Python, particularly Flask. If you have any questions or think this is stupid, please let me know. Thank you. I am quite inexperienced.

Comment: Why random and not sequence? (i.e. Give each time <last_id>+1)

Comment: generate id and check it in database before insert it.

Comment: Maybe you want to check python [uuid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python) library

Comment: Why not just let the database generate an ID and then store the type separately?  Your URLs don't have to map directly to IDs if you don't want them to.

Comment: @SeanVieira I haven't learned how to delete posts yet, so I thought that was standard procedure. It seems it would be easier to just use the db's autoincrement. Thanks for the assistance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Taking random 5 digits number can result in re-using same id twice (small number space)

You can do one of the following solutions:

1. Use bigger id space, you can use the standard uuid which looks like `12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678`. You can see how to use it [How to create a GUID/UUID in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python)
2. You can give ids in a certain order, like <last_given_id> +1 each time, this guarantee you don't re-use id until you get to the maximum.
3. You can also use @Satish Sharma suggestion, to check each time if id is in the db already. However, I don't think this is a good solution. it seems to me like an unwanted big overhead for each insertion.