# I want to upload a file to azure blob using python in blocks. (using-put_block)

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a file to the azure blob using python. I want to do the same using put_block by splitting the file into small parts then uploading them then combining. so that in case of large files, it does not fail. Can someone help me with this? I tried multiple solutions on StackOverflow. Nothing is working

```
from  azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

def uploadFile():
    accountey="account-key"
    accountName="account-name"
    containerName="container-name"

    blobService =BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountey )
    blobService.create_container(containerName)
    blobService.create_blob_from_path(containerName, "image1.jpg", "./images/python.jpg")

uploadFile()
```

I tried this also this is not working:

```
def upload():
    blob_service.create_container(container_name, None, None, False)
    #blob_service.put_block_blob(container_name, blob_name, '', 'BlockBlob')

    chunk_size = 65536
    block_ids = []
    index = 0
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(chunk_size)
            if data:
                length = len(data)
                block_id = base64.b64encode(bytes(index))
                blob_service.put_block(container_name, blob_name, data, block_id)
                block_ids.append(block_id)
                index += 1
            else:
                break

    resp = blob_service.put_block_list(container_name, blob_name, block_ids)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried (because you mentioned you tried certain things) and what's not working.

Comment: @GauravMantri I added the code which i tried but its not working

Comment: I am guessing that you're getting `Specified blob or block content is not valid` error.

Comment: Please add the errors you receive from the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see with your code is that you're using your `index` variable for creating block id. **Please note that the block ids must be of same length**. In your case, 1st 10 blocks (0 - 9) will have one length and then next 90 blocks (10 - 99) blocks will have different lengths and that will cause your blob upload to fail.

Two possible solutions:

1. Pad your `index` variable: You can pad the `index` variable with appropriate number of zeros so that they are of equal length. For example, you could do something like `0000`, `0001`....`0009`, `0010`...
2. Use UUID for creating block ids. Please see this post for more details: [How to create a GUID/UUID in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python).

I wrote a blog post about it some time ago that you might find useful: https://gauravmantri.com/2013/05/18/windows-azure-blob-storage-dealing-with-the-specified-blob-or-block-content-is-invalid-error/.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the question code is probably not working as is because blob_service.put_block_list expects `BlobBlock` instances to access the list of block_ids to commit...
Probably need
`block_ids.append(BlobBlock(block_id))` instead.