# Set unique field in list of dictionaries to be inserted into mongo db

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a list of dictionaries that look something like this;

```
json_data = [
  {
    "CODE": "018906",
    "X": "29813.66349",
    "Y": "28697.520760000003"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "018907",
    "X": "30041.8389",
    "Y": "28602.98724"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "018910",
    "X": "31966.120789999997",
    "Y": "29115.75337"
  },
]
```

I tried to insert `json_data` into a mongodb collection `mongo_collection`.

`mongo_collection.insert_many(json_data)`

It ran successfully. However, I want the key field `CODE` to be unique and insert should fail if there is a duplicate. The line above will insert every document even if there is duplicate `CODE`. How can I make `CODE` key unique? I am open to using python libraries like mongoengine.

I would like `CODE` to be something like a primary key in a relational database.

I am using python 3.7, mongodb 4.2.7 and pymongo.

Comment: Generate an UUID for each record, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python or are you looking for a running sequence ?

Comment: @Sushanth, No need running sequence. As long as the field can be kept unique like in a relational database, that will be good enough.

Comment: Then you can go with UUID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting,
You would need to create an `index` in MongoDB and mark `CODE` field as a unique index

[creating index in mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#examples)

```
db.mongo_collection.createIndex({CODE:1}, {unique:true})
```

This would ensure you get a duplicate key error if you try to insert `CODE` that already exists.

If you don't have access to MongoDB server.

You would need to populated `_id` with value as same as `CODE`. Since _id is a default primary index in mongo.

```
json_data = [
  {
    "_id": "018906",
    "CODE": "018906",
    "X": "29813.66349",
    "Y": "28697.520760000003"
  },
  {
    "_id": "018907",
    "CODE": "018907",
    "X": "30041.8389",
    "Y": "28602.98724"
  },
  {
    "_id": "018910",
    "CODE": "018910",
    "X": "31966.120789999997",
    "Y": "29115.75337"
  },
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you determine `{CODE:1}`? Why 1 and not some other number?

Comment: `{field:1}` here '1' indicates the creation of ascending index i.e. when indexes are created they will be sorted in ascending order.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#examples

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question to build on Anurag Wagh's answer as the syntax he used is not python. I have marked his answer as the correct one.

Since I am using pymongo, the syntax of the code should be;

```
import pymongo
mongo_collection.create_index([("CODE", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```